# Dynamic metric counter in spring boot - prometheus pushgateway

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, prometheus-pushgateway

I have an incoming event (to a spring boot application)in json format that contains a field called "component".
I need to create a metrics counter and push to prometheus pushgateway per-component.
There should be individual counters for every type of component. 
How to achieve this?

Comment: You can use a hashmap for this. hashmap.put(component.name(), counter++) will solve it.

Comment: How do you use prometheus pushgateway to implement a counter metric? What is the curl command? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can implement component for that.
Autowire MeterRegistry

```
private MeterRegistry registry;
```

And put map of counters inside.

```
private Map<String, Counter> counters = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

add method:

```
public void increment(String componentName){
  Counter counter = counters.get(componentName);
  if(counter == null) {
    counter = Counter.builder("your.metrics.name").tags("component", componentName).register(registry);
    counters.put(tagValue, counter);
  }
  counter.increment();
}
```